# Linking UserForm answers to change filepath in a Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have a summary workbook which pulls data from multiple excel workbooks saved in a folder. Each folder contains workbooks for data for a specific year and month. For example, C:\Desktop\Summaries\MONTH YEAR

I also have a UserForm that lets you choose the year and month. I would like for the answers from my UserForm to inform the file path.
[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IMUWv.png)

I would like to change the Month and Year of this file path depending on what is chosen in my UserForm

For example, if I want to pull data for February 2021, I will choose February and 2021 from my UserForm. When I press submit, I then would like my file path to change to C:\Desktop\Summaries\February 2021

Then my code will run to summarise the data in that folder. **How do I link my UserForm answers to a change in my file path?**

See below the code I use to summarise:

```
Dim desWS As Worksheet, srcWB As Workbook
Set desWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
Dim LastRow As Long
Const strPath As String = "C:\Desktop\Summaries\MONTH YEAR"
ChDir strPath
strExtension = Dir(strPath & "*.xlsx")
Do While strExtension <> ""
    Set srcWB = Workbooks.Open(strPath & strExtension)
    With srcWB.Sheets("Macro")
           desWS.Cells(desWS.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 22).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Range("C3:C24").Value)
    End With
    srcWB.Close False
    strExtension = Dir
Loop
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code, please:

```
Sub ProcessSpecificPath() 'called by 'Submit' button or being its code
 Dim desWS As Worksheet, srcWB As Workbook, foldPath As String
 Dim strExtension As String
 
 Set desWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data")
 Const strPath As String = "C:\Desktop\Summaries\"
 
 If Me.ComboMonth.Value = "" Or Me.ComboYear.Value = "" then Exit Sub 'an information Message would be good, too...
 foldPath = strPath & Me.ComboMonth.Value & " " & Me.ComboYear.Value 'you must use your real combo names
 strExtension = Dir(foldPath & "\" & "*.xlsx")
 Do While strExtension <> ""
    Set srcWB = Workbooks.Open(foldPath & "\" & strExtension)
    With srcWB.Sheets("Macro")
        desWS.cells(desWS.rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0).Resize(, 22).Value = _
                            Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(.Range("C3:C24").Value)
    End With
    srcWB.Close False
    strExtension = Dir
 Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi FaneDuru, that works thanks! Do you know how to make a popup appear for when a year and data are chosen that don't have any data in that folder? For example, I choose 2022 and February but that folder for my file path is empty, can a message come up to say "No workbooks saved in February 2022 folder"?

Comment: @MacroNewbie: Glad I could help!

Answer (score 0):

As there is not further information regarding the userform I suggest to have a look at the following code. I assumed your comboboxes are named correspondingly. This is example code you in the class module of the userform

```
Option Explicit

Private mCancelled As Boolean
    
Public Property Get Cancelled() As Boolean
    Cancelled = mCancelled
End Property

Property Get Year() As String
    Year = cmbYear.Value
End Property
    
Property Get Month() As String
    Month = cmbMonth.Value
End Property

Private Sub UserForm_QueryClose(Cancel As Integer _
                                  , CloseMode As Integer)
        
    If CloseMode = vbFormControlMenu Then Cancel = True
            
    Hide
    mCancelled = True
    
End Sub
```

This is code to test it

```
Option Explicit

Sub GetValues()
            
    Dim frm As New UserForm1        
    frm.Show
    
    If frm.Cancelled = True Then
        MsgBox "The UserForm was cancelled."
    Else
        MsgBox "You entered: " & frm.Year & " - " & frm.Month
    End If
            
    Unload frm
    Set frm = Nothing
    
End Sub
```